# How do I quickly find the last number of elements matching some criterion in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have some array:

```
x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1])
```

And I want to find the number of consecutive `1`s at the end of the array. One way to do this is with a loop:

```
i = len(x) - 1
while x[i] == 1:
    i = i - 1
```

Now I can look at `i` and work out the number of `1`s in the back of `x`. However, in my real-world example `x` can be very large, as can the number of `1`s, so I want a solution that:

1. Doesn't use loops, and
2. Doesn't traverse the whole array

Comment: Write a C extension (use Cython) or use `numba`. Both would use a loop.

Comment: If the last element of the array is not a `1`, what is the value you need to get as per your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree about using Cython or `numba` to speed up a loop and traverse just the array tail but if you want to give it a try with pure `numpy` I'd say something like the following could do:

```
np.argwhere(x[::-1] != 1).ravel()[0]
```

Reverse the array and take the first non-1 occurrence. It's traversing the whole array though... so it probably doesn't meet your needs.

EDIT: Here's a `numba` approach for completeness

```
from numba import jit
@jit
def count_trailing_ones(array):
    count = 0
    a = array[::-1]
    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        if a[i] == 1:
            count += 1
        else:
            return count
```

Here's a benchmark including also @J...S and @Kasramvd solutions, for a 800MB array with a couple million trailing ones. `numba` obviously wins but if you're going for `numpy` I'd say @J...S's `argmax` is the best.

```
In [102]: %timeit np.argwhere(x[::-1] != 1).ravel()[0]
631 ms ± 1.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [103]: %timeit np.argmax(x[::-1] != 1)
117 ms ± 417 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [104]: %timeit kas(x)
915 ms ± 3.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [105]: %timeit count_trailing_ones(x)
4.62 ms ± 16.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Test with `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5])`.

Comment: @Kasramvd read the whole answer please, there's a comment about the assumptions

Comment: Still that answer is not entirely correct. Please update and tell us how that check works thanks.

Comment: also, not sure what you're implying, both my solutions give `0` for your test array

Comment: @Kasramvd turns out the check is not needed at all, it works with `0` too flawlessly... will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is one vectorize approach:

```
In [50]: mask = x == 1

In [51]: T_inds = np.where(mask)[0]

In [52]: F_inds = np.where(~mask)[0]

In [53]: last_f_ind = np.where(T_inds[-1] > F_inds)[0][-1]

# x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5])
In [54]: T_inds[-1] - F_inds[last_f_ind]
Out[54]: 3
```

The trick is to find the index of latest item in non-one items that is lower than the index of latest one.

Also note that this approach will works for all the case where even ones are not at the trailing of your array (there are no other numbers after last 1s). But if you want to check that particular case where 1s are in end of your array here is a more concise approach:

```
x.size - np.where(x != 1)[0][-1] - 1
Out[27]: 3

# x != 1 will give you a mask of the indices where their value is not
# equal to one. Then you can use np.where() to find the index of last 
# occurrence of not one items. By subtracting it from size of array you 
# can get the number of consecutive ones.
```

Comment: @downvoter Please explain what's the reason of downvote so that I can fix it if there's any.

Answer (score 0):

If the last element is always a `1`, you could first reverse the array and then use `argmax` as in

```
np.argmax(x[::-1]!=1)
```

Which for the given array would give

```
3
```

You could use a check first to be sure if the last element is a `1` like

```
if(x[-1] == 1):
    print(np.argmax(x[::-1]!=1))
else:
    print(0)
```

Comment: Test with `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5])`.

Comment: @Kasramvd Do you mean that the `1`s not at the very end also should be considered? If so, I thought the loop that the OP gave considers only the `1`s at the very end of the array.

Comment: Yes and that's what I thought first time, then I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at searchsorted:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html#numpy.searchsorted

Use it in combination with np.where on the last element to return 0 if != 1.

**Note** This won't work if your array contain 0's as it will then try to insert the value at that point.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5])

# Create a lambda function that accepts x(array)
f = lambda x: np.where(x[-1] != 1, 0, np.searchsorted(x[::-1], 1, side='right'))

print(f(x)) # 3
print(f(y)) # 0
```

Comment: aren't you assuming `x >= 1` though?

Comment: Test with `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5])`.